# How to: MYSQL average from multiple columns excluding Null Values and Changing Number Divided By

Tags: mysql, null, average

Using the following MySQL 5.6 query
`SELECT sum(col1 + col2 + col3) / 3 AS Result FROM table1`

How can I do the same thing only ignoring NULL values? 
Also, adjusting the divide by number subtracting the NULL values?

Our lab uses a sensory panel to asses certain quality points of our product.
Each panel member scores -1, 0, or 1 for each sample.
For any given sample we can have 1 to 15 scores that they want averaged as 'Result'.

Reference to Question #24398431

Below is the Query I just tested.  I received no Errors but did not get any data at all returned.  I will take all the help I can get.

```
SELECT ndx, t_stamp, fv, name, lot, Pnl1, Pnl2, Pnl3, Pnl4, Pnl5, Pnl6, Pnl7, 
Pnl8, Pnl9, Pnl10, 
((sum((CASE WHEN (Pnl1 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl2 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl2 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl3 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl3 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl4 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl4 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl5 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl5 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl6 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl6 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl7 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl7 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl8 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl8 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl9 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl9 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl10 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl10 ELSE 0 END)))
/
(sum((CASE WHEN (Pnl1 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl2 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl3 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl4 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl5 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl6 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl7 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl8 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl9 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl10 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)))) AS Result
FROM vdk
WHERE Pnl1 IS NOT NULL AND Pnl2 IS NOT NULL AND Pnl3 IS NOT NULL AND Pnl4 IS 
NOT NULL AND Pnl5 IS NOT NULL
AND Pnl6 IS NOT NULL AND Pnl7 IS NOT NULL AND Pnl8 IS NOT NULL AND Pnl9 IS 
NOT NULL AND Pnl10 IS NOT NULL
AND t_stamp Between "{Root Container.Brew Harvest Table.brewTable.StartTime}" 
AND "{Root Container.Brew Harvest Table.brewTable.EndTime}"
```

Ok, Changing all the ANDs to ORs made it so I was returned one row of data, There should be 7 Rows returned according to the data that has been entered.
If I run the same query minus the sum case section, I get all 7 rows returned.
Below is the current query.  What am I missing, why only one row of data?

```
SELECT ndx, t_stamp, fv, name, lot, Pnl1, Pnl2, Pnl3, Pnl4, Pnl5, Pnl6, Pnl7, 
Pnl8, Pnl9, Pnl10, 
((sum((CASE WHEN (Pnl1 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl2 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl2 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl3 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl3 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl4 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl4 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl5 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl5 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl6 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl6 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl7 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl7 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl8 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl8 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl9 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl9 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl10 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl10 ELSE 0 END)))
/
(sum((CASE WHEN (Pnl1 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl2 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl3 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl4 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl5 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl6 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl7 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl8 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl9 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl10 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)))) AS Result
FROM vdk
WHERE Pnl1 IS NOT NULL OR Pnl2 IS NOT NULL OR Pnl3 IS NOT NULL OR Pnl4 IS 
NOT NULL OR Pnl5 IS NOT NULL
OR Pnl6 IS NOT NULL OR Pnl7 IS NOT NULL OR Pnl8 IS NOT NULL OR Pnl9 IS 
NOT NULL OR Pnl10 IS NOT NULL
AND t_stamp Between "{Root Container.Brew Harvest Table.brewTable.StartTime}" 
AND "{Root Container.Brew Harvest Table.brewTable.EndTime}"
```

Comment: So you want the total of each row's average not null values?

Comment: As I commented on the answer below, you should probably use OR not AND; but you could make it more succinct by `COALESCE(col1, col2, col3, and so on ) IS NOT NULL`. `COALESCE` returns the first non-null; and null if all are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Query below gave me the result I was looking for.
Thank you RToyo and Uueerdo, I would not have got this working without your help.

```
SELECT ndx, t_stamp,fv, name, lot, TankTmp, gcBut, gcPent, (gcBut+gcPent) AS gcTot,
gcIntStHx, gcExtbut, gcExtpent, gcExtrsp, (gcBut*2) AS histBut, (gcPent*2) AS 
histPent, ((gcBut*2)+(gcPent*2)) AS histTot,
Initial, Pnl1, Pnl2, Pnl3, Pnl4, Pnl5, Pnl6, Pnl7, Pnl8, Pnl9, Pnl10,
(((CASE WHEN (Pnl1 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl2 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl2 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl3 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl3 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl4 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl4 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl5 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl5 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl6 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl6 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl7 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl7 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl8 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl8 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl9 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl9 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl10 IS NOT NULL) THEN Pnl10 ELSE 0 END))
/
((CASE WHEN (Pnl1 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl2 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl3 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl4 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl5 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl6 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl7 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl8 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl9 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+(CASE WHEN (Pnl10 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))) AS Result,
note
FROM vdk
WHERE t_stamp Between "{Root Container.Brew Harvest Table.brewTable.StartTime}" 
AND "{Root Container.Brew Harvest Table.brewTable.EndTime}"
ORDER BY t_stamp ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple method that is often used in SQL is `case` statements. You can use a case statement to evaluate col1, col2, and col3 to see if they are null, and then output either the col1/2/3 value (for the numerator), or 1 or 0 for the denominator.

MySQL may have specific functions to help with this (for example, the `case` statements could be rewritten with the `if` function), but `case` is understood by most RDBMSes.

Here is an example of how you could do it - I've expanded out the numerator and denominator to make it a little bit clearer what is happening.

```
select
    (
        -- Numerator (output col1/2/3 value when not null)
        sum
        (
            -- col1
            (case when (col1 is not null) then col1 else 0 end)
            -- col2
            + (case when (col2 is not null) then col2 else 0 end)
            -- col3
            + (case when (col3 is not null) then col3 else 0 end)
        )
        /
        -- Denominator
        sum
        (
            -- col1
            (case when (col1 is not null) then 1 else 0 end)
            -- col2
            + (case when (col2 is not null) then 1 else 0 end)
            -- col3
            + (case when (col3 is not null) then 1 else 0 end)
        )
    ) as Result
from
    table1
where
    col1 is not null
    or col2 is not null
    or col3 is not null
```

A few things to note:

- I've included a `where` clause to exclude any rows where col1, col2, and col3 are null. This is to prevent the denominator from being 0, which would result in a divide by 0 error. This is not required if you **only** return the `sum` column (unless all rows in the table only have null values), but as soon as you add another column to your list of select columns, then it will evaluate this `Result` column for every single row, so you want to make sure you don't pull any that could result in a divide by zero error. Consider the "could my query divide by zero" problem, and balance it with the query's execution cost (if there are no indexes on col1/col2/col3, then you may see selection performance degradation)
- If you are finding that your `Result` is returning an integer instead of a float value (eg 5/3 is coming out as 2, instead of 1.6667), you will need to `convert` either the numerator or denominator to float. The basic idea is that if the `sum` values are determined to be `int` values, then MySQL will "divide an int by an int", and the datatype of the result will also be an int. But if you divide an int by a float (or a float by an int), then the result will be a float datatype.

Comment: Actually, there should only be a divide by zero issue if all rows have only null values. _Though I am not entirely sure this calculates the value the OP is looking for._

Comment: @Uueerdo Thanks, good observation. I'll edit the answer to make it clear that the divide by zero issue only occurs if the query includes other columns as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  i am a real rookie at this.

Comment: Another note: the ANDs are only going to allow rows that have no NULL values at all, rather than rows that have at least one non-NULL; OR should be used.

Comment: @Uueerdo Once again, thank you for pointing that out! It's been corrected in the answer. As your comment on the OP pointed out, `coalesce` would be useful here, but I want to keep the answer relatively easy to understand, and RDBMS neutral.